# What wines pair well with vegetarian dishes?

Tags: wine, pairing

What wines pair well with vegetarian or vegan dishes? White wines?

Comment: I don’t think there is a single answer. It depends on the dish. Have you tried searching on wine pairings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was brought up in the fashion that one served red wine with beef and white wine with most fish dishes. But vegetarian dishes are something all together.

> **Vegetarian Dish Pairing**
>
> **White Wines**
>
> **Pinot Gringo**
>
> - Veggie wraps
>
>   - bright salads
>   - pasta with cream sauce
>   - bruchetta
>
> **Chardonnay**
>
> - Starchy foods such as potatoes or risotto
>
>   - Spring peas
>   - Corn
>   - Roasted vegetables
>
> **Riesling**
>
> - Thai food
>
>   - Curry
>   - Summer BBQ
>   - Cashews
>   - Mexican Dishes
>
> **Gewurztraminer**
>
> - German foods
> - Cheeses
> - Cajun Cuisine
> - Kimchee
> - Indian Cuisine
>
> **Red Wines**
>
> **Chianti**
>
> - Pasta with tomato sauce
> - Caprese
> - Veggie pizza
>
> **Merlot**
>
> - Veggie Burgers
> - Olives
> - Avocados
>
> **Cabernet Sauvignon**
>
> - Lentil Soup
> - Garlic
> - Walnuts
> - Eggplants
>
> **Pinot Noir**
>
> - Mushrooms
> - Bread and olive oil
> - Mediterranean Foods
>
> [Quick Guide to Vegetarian Wine Pairings](http://thewanderlustkitchen.com/quick-guide-vegetarian-wine-pairings/)

Pairing rules are not set in stone, but there are a few friendly guidline to follow.

> **Match Wine Flavors With Food Flavors**
>
> Specific body and color types and their flavors are also elements to consider when you are pairing vegan foods and wine. For example, when choosing white wine, a light-bodied flavor, such as Vermentino, Pinot Grigio and Viognier all go well with pasta dishes, salads and stir-fry vegetables because they will not overpower the modest flavor of these foods. If you are barbecuing veggie burgers or preparing baked potatoes on the grill, consider choosing a classic white Chardonnay, Sauvignon Blanc or Riesling, which make a fine complement to the taste of grilled foods.
>
> If you prefer red wine, then go with Granache for veggie burgers and sweet potatoes, and try a Merlot for olive-based dishes and grilled asparagus. The most important aspect of pairing wine with a vegan meal is to choose flavors that will not overpower the food. For example, avoid pairing a robust, full-bodied red wine with a simple summer salad or pairing a sweet wine with a tart pesto and lemon dish.
>
> While you might make a few errors when you first start pairing wines and vegan dishes, you should never be afraid to experiment and come up with a few interesting combinations of you own. - [5 Tips for Pairing Wines With Vegan Dishes](https://learn.winecoolerdirect.com/vegan-wine-pairings/)

And by the way: **Bon Appetite!**